# How can I see the POST parameters through Powershell when using Get-WebRequest method?

Tags: powershell, iis

I am working on a simple PowerShell script which will allow me to inspect all incoming web requests to my IIS. Script works quite well, however it appears that I cannot see the POST parameters sent from the client to the server. If the method is 'GET' these are shown fine on the the URL, but the method is 'POST' these are not.

These are the details that I can see for every request. As you can see, I cannot see the post parameters:

```
requestId       : fc00000680003d08
connectionId    : fc00000660003d07
verb            : POST
url             : /test.php?method=getCustomers
siteId          : 2
localPort       : 443
hostName        : m.mytestdomain.com
clientIpAddress : 127.0.0.1
timeElapsed     : 313
pipeLineState   : 128
timeInState     : 313
currentModule   : IsapiModule
timeInModule    : 313
localIpAddress  : 127.0.0.1
RunspaceId      : 0e0d6f6f-24ec-44f7-8097-adb9932c2f7f
Attributes      : {Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute, Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute, Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute, Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationAttribute…}
ChildElements   : {}
ElementTagName  : request
Methods         :
Schema          : Microsoft.IIs.PowerShell.Framework.ConfigurationElementSchema
```

Any ideas?
thank you.

Comment: What's the context for your script? Where is it running / how is it running? Where is it getting the data from? If you post the code with the issue it might be easier to see what the problem is...

Comment: I just run it on my own PC, nothing complicated. I have IIS installed. I place a simple post request and then run on PowerShell the command Get-WebRequest. It will then return the above. What i need is to be able to get the POST parameters too.

Comment: Ok, so just to check I understand your question, it’s basically “using Get-WebRequest from the WebAdministration powershell module, how do you read the POST data for a request sent to IIS”. Not sure I know the answer to that, but at least the question is clearer :-)

Comment: I prefer the problem to be on the post, so please check if there is a problem with your post method.

Comment: @samwu not sure what you mean 'problem to be on the post'. That's where the problem is.

Comment: I mean there may be a problem with your post method.